# How to build an RNN with input as character but output a sequence of tokens?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Let’s assume I have “abbcab”-> {“Apple”,”Banana”}, “Bibb”-> {“Carrot”} so the output is a sequence of various length, but I can pad it to be the same length.  My problem, how do I create a simple LSTM model that takes a string of characters of varying length and map it to a vector?  What should be the last layer to return the vector?

Comment: Look up "Association" in the Help

Answer (score 5):

This is a multilabel classification.

```
classes = Length@{"Apple", "Banana", "Carrot"};

net = NetChain[
  {
   EmbeddingLayer[8],
   LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16],
   SequenceLastLayer[],
   LinearLayer[classes],
   ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid]
   },
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Characters"}]
  ];

netT = NetTrain[net, {"abbcab" -> {1, 1, 0}, "Bibb" -> {0, 0, 1}}, MaxTrainingRounds -> 100]
```

[image]

```
netT@"abbcab"
```

> {0.822325, 0.864362, 0.163531}

```
netT@"Bibb"
```

> {0.219002, 0.200206, 0.798121}

You should do your own post-processing to select top-n classes.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!  Thank you very much for the speedy and clear answer

Comment: Can we have the output layer as tokens?  The problem in this case is where to set the cut off point